# Invoke tests classes from another Maven project

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven-2

I have 2 maven projects, one for the sources: **ProjSource**, containing one class: **Class-A**.. and another one: **ProjTest** containing a test class for Class-A named **Class-A-Test** .
I want my test class to be run when I call an mvn:install on ProjSource.

What is the simplest way to perform such thing? note that my experience with unit tests is very basic.. I don't know how to tell Maven that Class-A-Test is designed to test Class-A..

I followed the steps described using the maven-jar-plugin with test-jar Goal [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html) and defining the resulting *****************-tests.jar as a dependency for **ProjSource** with:

```
<type>test-jar</type>
<scope>test</scope>
```

but when i run an mvn:install, the output says that: *"There are no tests to run"*. Have I missed something ?

Any help is highly appreciable, and many thanks in advance !

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. don't do it that way. The maven way to do it is to have standard sources under `src/main/java` and test sources under `src/test/java`. By default, standard sources will be added to the resulting JAR, while tests in the test source dir will be executed automatically. This is well-tested behavior, why change it? **If you want / need a test jar, call jar:test-jar in the pom.xml of this project and use the buildhelper plugin to [attach the resulting artifact](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html) for deploy. That way you can keep the standard project layout and still have a test jar.**
2. if you insist on doing it, you would have to do it the other way around. The test project would have to have a dependency to the main project (you can't test what you don't know). I would suggest to just put the test code in `src/test/java` in the test project, then maven's magic can work the default way. **Insert bold text from above here, too.**

But the reason why the maven lifecycle was defined as it was is that failed tests are supposed to fail the build. There is no point in building a library that doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks Floyd,  I tried your suggestion but unfortunately that didn't work.. Now I'm trying to find a way to tell Maven that my Test Classes are packaged in a JAR file, and to go search for that jar when  executing the "test phase". <testSourceDirectory> is close to what I'm seeking, but this tag only accepts a folder as a source, not a JAR.. please note that these are my company's requirements, all tests are packaged in one Jar (done before start using maven...)